# microk8s Ingress can't access services (503)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, microk8s

I'm running microk8s v1.18.5 from snap on Ubuntu 20.04 with addons `ingress`, `dns`, `dashboard`, `helm3`, `storage`.

I'm trying to externally access running services such as `grafana` and `dashboard`. I've configured proxy services and ingresses as per docs:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: grafana
  namespace: ingress
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: monitoring-grafana.kube-system.svc.cluster.local
  ports:
    - port: 80
---
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: grafana-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "grafana.example.com"
      secretName: grafana-tls
  rules:
    - host: grafana.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: grafana
              servicePort: 80
            path: /
---
```

and

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: dashboard
  namespace: ingress
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: kubernetes-dashboard.kube-system.svc.cluster.local
  ports:
    - port: 443
---
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: dashboard-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "dashboard.example.com"
      secretName: dashboard-tls
  rules:
    - host: dashboard.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: dashboard
              servicePort: 443
            path: /
---
```

Trying to access either dashboard or grafana I get:

```
503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
openresty/1.15.8.1
```

What can I do to find the root cause?

I'm also running cert-manager and external-dns from helm3, could their config be related to the issue?

Comment: Can you post output of `kubectl get svc -A`? Are your pods running?

Comment: @KFC_ my output: https://pastebin.com/iDkH1CEc and thanks for taking a look. Pods are all running. I suspect ingress namespace is not what I needed to put the proxies in even though nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller is in ingress namespace.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to change your dashboard and grafana [service type](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#over-a-nodeport-service) to `NodePort` for ingress to work correctly.

Besides that Kubernetes dashboard for microk8s is accessible under `<master_node_ip>:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/` path so you have to mention it in either your URL or in your ingress manifest. When you `curl dashboard.example.com`
it gives you `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable` error. However when you enter full path it will show the website:

```
curl http://dashboard.example.com:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy

<!--
Copyright 2017 The Kubernetes Authors.

[...]
```

This is an example of ingress that will rewrite `/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy` to `/dashboard/`

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: grafana-ingress
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # Add https backend protocol support for ingress-nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
      sub_filter '<base href="/">' '<base href="/dashboard/">';
      sub_filter_once on;
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
    - host: dashboard.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /dashboard(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
              servicePort: 443
```